# Check how many instances of a script are already running using linux ps command

Tags: php, shell, cron

I have a cron job that takes about 5 minutes to complete and it's set to run every minute.
I know that the script gets executed faster as it would terminate but that's intentionally.
I want to have about 5 instances of this script running at the same time but as it is now, the server will just run too many instances till everything freezes.

That's why I want to perform a check at the beginning of each cron how many instances are already running and to immediately terminate if there are more than 5 running already.

How could I do that most effectively?

Online I found this snippet which might be a good solution:

```
exec("ps auxwww|grep cleaner.php|grep -v grep", $output);
print_r($output);
```

while `cleaner.php` is the script in question.

If I execute this script, I get the following output:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => root      4565  0.0  0.0   6184   776 ?        SNs  15:42   0:00 jailshell (user1) [4732] ell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [1] => user1  4732  0.0  0.0   6184   396 ?        SN   15:42   0:00 jailshell (user1) [init] ell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [2] => user1  4733  0.0  0.0 106056  1264 ?        SN   15:42   0:00 /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [3] => user1  4734  0.0  0.3 366452 15988 ?        SN   15:42   0:00 php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php
    [4] => root      4776  0.0  0.0   6184   776 ?        SNs  15:44   0:00 jailshell (user1) [4793] ell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [5] => user1  4793  0.0  0.0   6184   396 ?        SN   15:44   0:00 jailshell (user1) [init] ell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [6] => user1  4794  0.0  0.0 106056  1264 ?        SN   15:44   0:00 /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [7] => user1  4795  0.0  0.3 366452 16008 ?        SN   15:44   0:00 php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php
    [8] => root      6111  0.0  0.0   6184   776 ?        SNs  15:46   0:00 jailshell (user1) [6126] ell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [9] => user1  6126  0.0  0.0   6184   396 ?        SN   15:46   0:00 jailshell (user1) [init] ell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [10] => user1  6127  0.0  0.0 106056  1264 ?        SN   15:46   0:00 /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [11] => user1  6128  0.0  0.3 366452 15920 ?        SN   15:46   0:00 php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php
    [12] => root      6218  0.0  0.0   6184   776 ?        SNs  15:48   0:00 jailshell (user1) [7368] ell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [13] => user1  7368  0.0  0.0   6184   396 ?        SN   15:48   0:00 jailshell (user1) [init] ell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [14] => user1  7369  0.0  0.0 106056  1260 ?        SN   15:48   0:00 /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [15] => user1  7370  0.0  0.3 366452 15960 ?        SN   15:48   0:00 php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php
    [16] => root      7462  0.0  0.0   6184   776 ?        SNs  15:50   0:00 jailshell (user1) [7704] ell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [17] => user1  7704  0.0  0.0   6184   396 ?        SN   15:50   0:00 jailshell (user1) [init] ell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [18] => user1  7705  0.0  0.0 106056  1256 ?        SN   15:50   0:00 /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [19] => user1  7706  0.0  0.3 366452 15960 ?        SN   15:50   0:00 php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php
    [20] => root     11969  0.0  0.0   6184   772 ?        SNs  15:52   0:00 jailshell (user1) [11987] ll -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [21] => user1 11987  0.0  0.0   6184   392 ?        SN   15:52   0:00 jailshell (user1) [init] ell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [22] => user1 11992  0.0  0.0 106056  1264 ?        SN   15:52   0:00 /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [23] => user1 11993  0.2  0.3 366452 15888 ?        SN   15:52   0:00 php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php
    [24] => root     24158  0.0  0.0   6184   780 ?        SNs  15:30   0:00 jailshell (user1) [24232] ll -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [25] => user1 24232  0.0  0.0   6184   400 ?        SN   15:30   0:00 jailshell (user1) [init] ell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [26] => user1 24254  0.0  0.0 106056  1264 ?        SN   15:30   0:00 /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [27] => user1 24260  0.0  0.3 366448 15952 ?        SN   15:30   0:00 php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php
    [28] => root     28649  0.0  0.0   6184   772 ?        SNs  15:32   0:00 jailshell (user1) [29645] ll -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [29] => user1 29645  0.0  0.0   6184   392 ?        SN   15:32   0:00 jailshell (user1) [init] ell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [30] => user1 29647  0.0  0.0 106056  1264 ?        SN   15:32   0:00 /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [31] => user1 29648  0.0  0.3 366452 15972 ?        SN   15:32   0:00 php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php
    [32] => root     29821  0.0  0.0   6184   776 ?        SNs  15:34   0:00 jailshell (user1) [29840] ll -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [33] => user1 29840  0.0  0.0   6184   396 ?        SN   15:34   0:00 jailshell (user1) [init] ell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [34] => user1 29843  0.0  0.0 106056  1260 ?        SN   15:34   0:00 /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [35] => user1 29845  0.0  0.3 366452 15984 ?        SN   15:34   0:00 php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php
    [36] => root     30055  0.0  0.0   6184   776 ?        SNs  15:36   0:00 jailshell (user1) [30090] ll -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [37] => user1 30090  0.0  0.0   6184   396 ?        SN   15:36   0:00 jailshell (user1) [init] ell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [38] => user1 30101  0.0  0.0 106056  1260 ?        SN   15:36   0:00 /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [39] => user1 30108  0.0  0.3 366452 15968 ?        SN   15:36   0:00 php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php
    [40] => root     31311  0.0  0.0   6184   776 ?        SNs  15:38   0:00 jailshell (user1) [31332] ll -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [41] => user1 31332  0.0  0.0   6184   396 ?        SN   15:38   0:00 jailshell (user1) [init] ell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [42] => user1 31333  0.0  0.0 106056  1260 ?        SN   15:38   0:00 /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [43] => user1 31336  0.0  0.3 366452 15976 ?        SN   15:38   0:00 php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php
    [44] => root     31610  0.0  0.0   6184   776 ?        SNs  15:40   0:00 jailshell (user1) [31675] ll -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [45] => user1 31675  0.0  0.0   6184   396 ?        SN   15:40   0:00 jailshell (user1) [init] ell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [46] => user1 31680  0.0  0.0 106056  1260 ?        SN   15:40   0:00 /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell -c php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
    [47] => user1 31685  0.0  0.3 366452 15972 ?        SN   15:40   0:00 php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php
)
```

Now I am a bit confused that some instances are run under `user1` and some under `root` and also about the jailshell.

What line of the output from above means the script gets currently executed 1 time or is the script really being executed 48 times currently? I suppose more filtering is needed.

Is this even the best solution for what I try to achieve?

Comment: can you list the crontab contents for lines calling cleaner.php using crontab -u root -l and crontab -u user1 -l. Also could you give some information on what version of linux you are running.

Comment: Output for both is `Array
(
    [0] => SHELL="/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell"
    [1] => * * * * * php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php >/dev/null 2>&1
)` it's a cpanel WHM setup (CentOS 6.4)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with cpanel/jailshell and using it to run cronjobs but I have tried to answer the question the best I can.

There is a pattern that emerges from the output you listed in that the start time of processes is clearly in groups of 4 which makes me think that each group of 4 is one instance of your cleaner running. A parent process is perhaps forking sub process. You can get the parent process by using “ps -ef” command to validate this theory.

If this theory is correct you could then use

```
exec("ps auxwww | grep cleaner.php | grep -v grep | grep -v jailshell”, $output);
```

which would return just return

```
php /home/user1/public_html/crons/cleaner.php
```

which should then give you the actual number of processes running if you used a count on $ouput.

In terms of implementation you could use a table in a database that stores a value with the current number of cleaners running and increment and decrement the value as crons stop and start. You would also need to do this with some form of transaction so updates to the table are atomic.

However the fact that the cron runs every minute and for a period of 5 minutes makes me think that you need to perhaps look at making cleaner.php more efficient so that you don't need 5 instances of it running. This then means you can remove the problem of only having 5 instances of the cleaner running at once.

With my comment on your original question it seems that perhaps cpanel/jailshell has duplicated crons as you got a result for both

crontab -u root -l and crontab -u user1 -l

so I would make sure that your cron first is only executed once and not by both the root and user1 users.

Comment: Great post, could you tell me why you suggest a database instead of directly executing that command each time a cron runs?

Comment: I suggest the database simply as an alternate solution but either solution should be ok provided that the output of your ps command is correct.

Comment: Maybe a bit OT but I'm currently fighting with it: When I run the script with this exec in my browser it shows correct results but when the cron executes the script, it only "sees" itself and therefore only sees 1 instance all the time no matter how many are actually running, can you assume what could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

In WHM under "Tweak Settings" -> "System", option titled: "Jailed /proc mount method". If you set it to "Always mount full /proc", this will allow CRON launched scripts to see ALL of the processes via ps and top. If you keep jailshell enabled, you still have to ignore them (i.e. grep -v jailshell), but the counts will be accurate again.

Explanation and History:

This exact issue has been plaguing me for years! I have numerous scripts, across several of my sites that CRON runs every minute, but the scripts count instances to keep only a single copy of itself running. A few of them count and allow a specific number of instances.

However, a few years ago, all of that stopped working after a cPanel update sometime back in 2013. I didn't know, at the time, what happened but I noticed that there were multiple instances of my script now, running under "jailshell" PIDs. So, I modified my scripts to count those. Didn't work. I changed it to ignore the jailshell copies "grep -v jailshell" but that didn't work fully. My scripts would never run. They would say there were too many instances. So, I increased the counts to compensate and got them running, but over time, multiple copies would spawn far beyond the limit I imposed. Within days, there would be hundreds of instances and the server would grind to a halt.

Tonight, I finally found the solution.

I found this cPanel thread: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/jailshell-users-not-seeing-processes-in-ps-or-top.351271/

Which sounds like my issue. cPanel says it's not a problem, because they couldn't reproduce it from the command line, but they weren't testing from a shell created by CRON. That is the problem. When CRON runs, it can only see processes launched in ITS shell; not all processes for that user.

So, a bit more digging and I found mention of cPanel making the jailshell also mount /proc with limited capabilities. However, they added an override at one point. It can be found in WHM under "Tweak Settings" -> "System", titled: "Jailed /proc mount method". If you set it to "Always mount full /proc", this will allow CRON launched scripts to see ALL of the processes via ps and top. If you keep jailshell enabled, you still have to ignore them (i.e. grep -v jailshell), but the counts will be accurate again. Hooray!

I tested this fully tonight and my scripts are working again but not spawning out of control.

Note: This does present a security liability in that a shared hosting user (or compromised site on this server) could potentially escape the jail shell using information derived from ps and top. So use with caution. I am willing to take the risk, because I keep my sites updated, write my own code, and cannot use the server for much otherwise. Your situation may warrant more caution, however.